# Получение настроек комнаты в openfire при её создании

Tags: java, плагин, handlers, openfire

У меня есть плагин с обработчиком создания комнаты. В нём мне нужно получить настройки создаваемой комнаты, включая maxUsers. Вне зависимости как создаётся комната - через панель администратора или через rest api плагин, я всегда получаю результат 30 (значение по умолчанию).

```java
public void roomCreated(room jid) {
   // ...
   MUCRoom mucRoom = XMPPServer.getInstance()
      .getMultiUserChatManager()
      .getMultiUserChatService(room)
      .getChatRoom(room.getNode());
   // ...
   int maxUsers = mucRoom.getMaxUsers(); // всегда 30 в этом обработчике
   // ...
}
```

Для примере, в обработчике изменения настроек комнаты, maxUsers правильный.

Я неправильно получаю количество пользователей или обработчик запускается после создания комнаты, но до применения его дополнительных опций?

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл одно решение - достаточно запустить код в Thread'е с задержкой (100-200 мс) вначале.

Может, эти не самое красивое решение, но то, что в обработчике события создания комнаты возвращается неправильное значение maxUsers, тоже нехорошо.